# kableExtra not working when putting a picture as a content of a cell

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

I have a markdown file in which I have this header:

```
---

title: "Report" 
author: ''
date:  "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:

- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{amssymb}
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{tabularx}
- \usepackage[pages=some]{background}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{subcaption}
- \usepackage{array,blindtext}
- \usepackage{tcolorbox}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{titling}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
- \usepackage{geometry}
- \usepackage{framed, color}
- \usepackage{enumitem}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{threeparttablex}
- \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \AtBeginDocument{\let\maketitle\relax}
- \definecolor{titlepagecolor}{HTML}{E8F8F5}
- \definecolor{namecolor}{HTML}{787878}
- \definecolor{mygen}{HTML}{3AB5B1}
- \definecolor{mygen2}{HTML}{ABA8A7}
- \definecolor{mygen3}{HTML}{2D2D2D}
- \definecolor{mygen4}{HTML}{02A1B1}
- \definecolor{gene1}{HTML}{74c476}
- \definecolor{gene2}{HTML}{6CA26D}
- \definecolor{gene3}{HTML}{66c2a4}
- \definecolor{gene4}{HTML}{EBFFEB}
- \definecolor{lineacopertina}{HTML}{138D75}
- \definecolor{colorealtetesto}{HTML}{117864}
- \definecolor{shadecolor}{HTML}{3AB5B1}

---
```

and it works fine with every combination I run (i posted it because i've read that in some cases tha problem could be the preamble) but my problem is that when I try to generate a table in a for loop in which there is a picture as cell content for a column latex gives me an error and it fails in generating a pdf file, this are the lines of code:

```
  if(FTab$column[i]=="CAUSATIVO"){
    FTab$Interpretazione[i]<"\\includegraphics{\\\\192.168.0.10\\pic1.png} \\\\"
    
  }else if(FTab$column[i]=="PROTETTIVO"){
    FTab$Interpretazione[i]<-"\\includegraphics{\\\\192.168.0.10\\pic2.png} \\\\"
   
  }else{
    FTab$Interpretazione[i]<"\\includegraphics{\\\\192.168.0.10\\pic3.png} \\\\"

  }
}

 FTab<- FTab %>% select(1:5,7)
FTab %>% kable("latex", **escape = F**, booktabs = T, linesep = "") %>% kable_styling(latex_options = c("scale_down"))%>% row_spec(0, background = "#3AB5B1")}
```

when I try whit this code it gives me this error:

**! Argument of __kernel_file_name_expand_loop:w has an extra }.

par
l.216 \end{tabular}}**

if with the same code I swhitch on **escape=T** it doesn't interpret the latex codes and instead of the picture in the table there is the text.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Roberto Sirica. It seems there is an extra `}` in your code. Could you please try removing the last `}` from your `if else` function?

Comment: I tried to delete one bracket, but it gives me always the same error. The other bracket at the end is a typo because this if condition is inside afor loop, I apologize. I looked into the tex file generated and the bracket is at the end ot the tabular command, I checked all the brackets in the whole script and it seems that thay are matched, any suggestion?

Comment: This are the resulting .tex file lines where it gives me the error:

Comment: What about considering the `flextable` package, in order to insert images in your tables and knit some markdown files to pdf ? With flextable, you don't need to use latex style for rendering your images (i. e. `"\\includegraphics{\\\\192...} \\\\"`); but you'll need some R function (e.g., `flextable::compose()`). See here: https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/cell-content-1.html#images

And here: https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/knit_print.flextable.html#pdf-output

Comment: Thank you @ClémentLVD I tried the `flextable` package and this time all worked.

Answer (score 1):

This are the resulting .tex file lines where it gives me the error:

```
\vspace*{0.3cm}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\toprule
\cellcolor[HTML]{3AB5B1}{Gene} & \cellcolor[HTML]{3AB5B1}{SNP} & \cellcolor[HTML]{3AB5B1}{Variazione} & \cellcolor[HTML]{3AB5B1}{Allele di rischio} & \cellcolor[HTML]{3AB5B1}{Genotipo} & \cellcolor[HTML]{3AB5B1}{Interpretazione}\\
\midrule
LCT, MCM6 & rs4988235 & -13910 T>C & C & CC & \includegraphics[width=0.8cm, height=0.8cm]{\\192.168.21.57\genetica\ROBERTO\pics_18112020\faccinarossa.png} \\\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the `flextable` package, it's fine to insert images in tables, and knit some markdown files to .pdf, or even .docx output. See the [flextable manual](http://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/knit_print.flextable.html#pdf-output) and how-to insert images in your tables [here](https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/cell-content-1.html#images).